# How to configure the apache authorization chain for Kerberos (mod_auth_kerb) and SSL?

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, kerberos, single-sign-on, authorization

What directives and conditions to configure the Apache configuration as follows:

We try to authorize through Kerberos.

- If successful (What condition to use?), Then we redirect to URL1.
- Otherwise, we try to authorize through Certificates. If successful (`%{SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY} == "SUCCESS"`), then we redirect to URL2.
- Otherwise, redirect to URL3.

I tried through the directive and environment variable `%{REMOTE_USER}`, but the directive is processed before authentication, so `%{REMOTE_USER}` is not available.

I will be grateful for any ideas and hints.